# URL rewrite is exceeding the allowed maximum file size

Tags: asp.net, xml, web-config

We are using URL rewrite 2.1 on IIS10 and have a large set of redirect rules within a config file that is invoked from a web.config, this is all working fine. We now want to move the sites over to a new hosting but the rewrite config file size exceeds the allowed maximum, the hosting company are refusing to increase the size of the allowance. Since most of the redirect rules are valid (required for seo) is there any way we can get this to work by maybe splitting the rules into more than one config files e.g the following (results in a 500 server error) -

```
  <rewrite>
            <rules configSource="rewriteRules.config" />
            <rules configSource="simpleRules.config" />
   </rewrite>
```

All replies appreciated, thanks in advance.